# Mounted folder created as root instead of current user in Docker

Tags: docker

trying to mount a volume to my container from the `docker run` command.
It seems like the folder is always created as root instead of the container user. This makes it so that I'm lacking rights on the folder(cant create or write files for logging).

Doing some testing using this command:
`docker run -it --entrypoint /bin/bash -v $PWD/logs:/home/jboss/myhub/logs:rw myImage:latest`

If i now do the command: `ls -ld /logs` i get the result: `drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jun 12 13:01 logs/`

Here we can see that only the owner has write-rights. And root is the owner.
I would expect(I want) jboss to be the owner of this folder. Or at least that all users have read/write rights given the `:rw` option in the `-v` parameter

What am I not understanding here? How can i get it to work like I want?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

At the moment, this is a recurring issue with no simple answer.

There are two common approaches I hear of.

First involves `chown`ing the directory before using it.

```
RUN mkdir -p /home/jboss/myhub/logs ; chown -R jboss:jboss /home/jboss/myhub/logs
USER jboss
```

In case you need to access the files from your host system with a different user, you can `chmod` files that your app created inside the container with your jboss user.

```
$ chmod -R +rw /home/jboss/myhub/logs
```

The second approach, involves creating the files with appropriate `chmod` in `Dockerfile` (or in your host system) before running your application.

```
$ touch /home/jboss/myhub/logs/app-log.txt
$ touch /home/jboss/myhub/logs/error-log.txt
$ chmod 766 /home/jboss/myhub/logs/app-log.txt
$ chmod 766 /home/jboss/myhub/logs/error-log.txt
```

There certainly are more ways to achieve this, but I haven't yet heard of any more "native" solutions.
I'd like to find out an easier/more practical approach.

Comment: ended up just creating the folder and setting permission on it before running the container. Wish there was a better solution:(

Answer (score 5):

@trust512 has identified the problem correctly and also correctly stated that there are no universally agreed upon "good solutions" to the problem.  @trust512 has provided 2 kludgy solutions.

My solutions is not better - just an alternative.

**Mount the parent of the volume you are interested in.**

For example '/home/user' should be owned by user, but if I create a volume

```
docker volume create myhome
```

and mount it like

```
docker container run --mount type=volume,source=myhome,destination=/home/user ...
```

then `/home/user` will be owned by root.

However, if I do it like

```
docker volume create myhome &&
docker container run --mount type=volume,source=myhome,destination=/home alpine:3.4 mkdir /home/user &&
docker container run --mount type=volume,source=myhome,destination=/home alpine:3.4 chown 1000:1000 /home/user
```

then when I run

```
docker container run --mount type=volume,source=myhome,destination=/home ...
```

then `/home/user` will have the appropriate owner.