# Docker volume mount giving root ownership of parent directory

Tags: docker

I am using a docker and mounting something into the /home/(user) directory on the docker image using
`-v ~/.aws:/home/$(shell id -nu)/.aws`.  The issue is, since /home/(user) did not exist prior to creating the docker, /home/(user) ends up being owned by root.  This is causing issues for pip, sam-cli, etc because they are all attempting to store some information in the user home directory.

How can I avoid this situation without completely abandoning using a specific user?  I've tried using chown to change the ownership, but I always get 'Operation not Permitted.'

Pretty easy to reproduce

```
developer@desktopimage:~/AWS$ docker run --rm -it -v ~/.aws:/home/developer/.aws -v /etc/group:/etc/group:ro -v /etc/passwd:/etc/passwd:ro -u 1001:1001 alpine:latest ls -al /home/developer
total 12
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root          4096 Feb 25 14:09 .
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 Feb 25 14:09 ..
drwxr-xr-x    5 develope develope      4096 Feb  3 20:49 .aws
developer@desktopimage:~/AWS$ docker run --rm -it -v ~/.aws:/home/developer/.aws -v /etc/group:/etc/group:ro -v /etc/passwd:/etc/passwd:ro -u 1001:1001 alpine:latest ls -al /home
total 12
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 Feb 25 14:09 .
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 Feb 25 14:09 ..
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root          4096 Feb 25 14:09 developer
```

Comment: There's to 'right' fix for this. There are a couple of useful suggestions in https://stackoverflow.com/a/50820023/46433 Basically you need to ensure all the parent folders of the mount folder already exist with the correct permissions. i.e. You'll need to create them and chown them in the Dockerfile